# Storing and using a projects node_modules in a different folder

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I use Google Drive to house my projects, and syncing thousands of files every time I make a change in a dependency is frustrating.

I want to have the following structure with both VueJS and non-VueJS node projects:

```
Google\ Drive/
    +-- workspace/
    |   +-- project\ 1/
    |   |   +-- node_modules/
    |
    |   +-- project\ 2/
    |   |   +-- node_modules/
    |
    +-- project 1/
    |   `-- package.json
    |
    +-- project 2/
    |   `-- package.json
```

In this way I can set a "do not sync" on the `workspace` folder which contains the node_modules for each individual project. I have no idea how to link back and `npm i` to this directory, and various answers I've tried on StackOverflow haven't worked for me (probably because I am doing something wrong).

Running `npm i -g --prefix ~/test` in the folder `Google\ Drive/project\ 1/` simply creates a symlink at `~/test/node_modules/lib/node_modules/project\ 1/` back to the current directory meaning I still end up with `node_modules` inside `project\ 1` which is exactly what I do not want.

Comment: You may want to add the google-drive tag to this question to expand its reach.

Comment: @PeterVC the only tag I saw was for the SDK :(

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @user319862 I ended up using a service called InSync which allows me to selectively ignore folders matching a pattern at specific locations, or any location. You could also roll `rsync` yourself and watch the file system but I couldn't be bothered doing that (read: re-creating what InSync is). InSync is a paid service.

Comment: @user319862 I have also just discovered RClone which is like InSync but free and supports more providers (e.g. Dropbox) too, their website is https://rclone.org/ but that may change. Future persons Google, "RClone" and you should be able to find it.